# Missing DefaultManagedExecutorService dependency when migrating Wildfly from Java 8 to 11

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, java-11

I have the following code that worked fine in Wildfly 18/Java 8:

```
@Stateless
public class FormulaRunBean {

    @Resource
    private ManagedExecutorService executor;

    // ........

}
```

When I switched to Wildfly 20/Java 11, I get the following error when I run Wildfly (no compilation issues).
Apparently it cannot find `ManagedExecutorService`:

> WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
> service jboss.naming.context.java.comp."visualbank-2.0"."visualcode-ejb-2.0".FormulaRunBean.**DefaultManagedExecutorService** (missing) dependents: [service
> jboss.naming.context.java.comp."visualcode-2.0"."visualcode-ejb-2.0".FormulaRunBean.env."visualcode.ejb.bi.ds.formula.run.FormulaRunBean".**executor**]
> WFLYCTL0448: 747 additional services are down due to their
> dependencies being missing or failed

How to fix this? Is this a Java 11 issue or something else?

Comment: Have a look at the old and new standalone.xml files and compare the ` <managed-executor-service>`tags. The error looks like some configuration / naming issue. I've seen some of those, but can't say anything about the ExecutorService though. Maybe a project clean might help as well, but I get you already tried that.

Comment: yes, a configuration was missing in standalone.xml